# CentOS7 mysqlserver download error

Tags: linux, mysql, sql-server, centos7

```
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa httpd
httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa php
php-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa mysql
[root@localhost bin]#
```

I am a beginner of linux and I was trying to install httpd, php and mysql.
but I got a error msg when i installed for mysql.

```
> [root@localhost bin]# yum install mysql mysql-server Loaded plugins:
> fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  *
> base: mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com  * extras: mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com
> * updates: mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com Package 1:mariadb-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
> No package mysql-server available. Nothing to do
```

and i also tried to do it as below.

```
>  [root@localhost bin]# yum install mariadb-server mariadb-libs mariadb
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from
> cached hostfile  * base: mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com  * extras:
> mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com  * updates: mirror.oasis.onnetcorp.com
> 
> Package 1:mariadb-server-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and
> latest version Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 already
> installed and latest version Package 1:mariadb-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64
> already installed and latest version Nothing to do
```

i can not install the mysql server. It seems to be installed when i install at first so i did the command "service mysqld start"

```
[root@localhost bin]# service mysqld start                                      Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

but it is same happening. plz help me to do ~~~ Thanks

Comment: Since [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) is a MySQL fork and already installed you can either use that (`systemctl start mariadb`) or you'll have to remove it before installing MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It is already installed, that's what yum is telling you.
You should start it with `systemctl start mariadb`, service is now deprecated

Comment: how can I check that was serviced ???

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# systemctl start mariadb  --> no show the info

Comment: yes it only shows you when it fails. You can check the result with systemctl status mariadb.